# Initializing vector of vectors

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

Is the following code

```
vector<vector<int> > v(3,5);
```

legal C++ 98? Is it legal C++11?

It compiles with MSVS 2010 and gives a vector of size 3, each of which elements is a vector of size 5. It fails to compile with MSVS 2013 and MSVS "14".

Comment: Not legal as `std::vector` has an [explicit constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) taking the size.

Comment: I believe this was a bug in the VS2010 stdlib that caused the `vector` constructor taking two iterators to be invoked. That constructor is not supposed to participate in overload resolution when the two arguments are integral types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The one-argument size  constructor of `std::vector` is explicit, so just `5` won't work, as it is not implicitly convertible to `std::vector<int>`. You need this:

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > v(3, std::vector<int>(5));
```

This has always been the case since C++98 and hasn't changed since (although the actual constructor signatures have changed regarding default arguments; see the [cppreference entry](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) for a history of the signatures).